# Java -- method returning correct value when called outside of class but not when called from inside?

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, methods

I'm doing basics of Java,so while doing a larger program I got stuck on this thing which I thought I'll try to fix in a separate program. But it's still baffling me.
I've broken down the issue to just one thing which I can't explain
Here is the code.

```
package Basics;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Polygon {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;

    Polygon(int n) {
        this.num = n;
    }

    int[] getSides() {
        int[] sides = new int[this.num];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter length of side " + (i + 1));
            sides[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
        return sides;
    }

    int[] sides = this.getSides();

}

class runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygon rectangle = new Polygon(4);
        int[] sides = rectangle.getSides();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rectangle.sides));
        
    }

}
```

And here is the output

```
run:
Enter length of side 1
5
Enter length of side 2
4
Enter length of side 3
3
Enter length of side 4
2
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[]
[]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

So as you can see when called from *outside the class*, the getSides() method returns the correct value, which is whatever the user entered. But from inside it does not?
I'm pretty sure this is somehow a stupid or noob question and that there's something huge I'm missing but I really need help with this
Whats causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: in java class names start with a capital letter so its better to write the `runner` as `Runner`

Comment: sorry! didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Polygon {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;    // Java default value for integers is zero
 
    Polygon(int n) {
        this.num = n; // The value is changed when an object is created;
    }

    int[] getSides() {
        int[] sides = new int[this.num]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter length of side " + (i + 1));
            sides[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        return sides;
    }

    int[] sides = this.getSides(); // This method call to getSides will be executed before the Constructor, using all the instance variables(so, the variable num is 0)
}
```

Your problem, is that your assign the variable sides calling the method *getSides()*, since this assignment will run before the constructor, the variable *num* is 0(default value), so no iteration is done.

***Example*** Method executing before the constructor

```
public class Polygon {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    int[] sides = this.getSides();  // Assign a variable with  the return of a method, this is executed before the constructor

    Polygon(int n) {
        System.out.println("I am the constructor");
        this.num = n;
    }

    int[] getSides() {
        System.out.println("I will be executed before the constructor");
        int[] sides = new int[this.num];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter length of side " + (i + 1));
            sides[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
        return sides;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Polygon(5);
    }
```

Comment: so how do i get the constructor to be called first?

Comment: What? The constructor is the special method, it is executed before anyone else. 

 Polygon rectangle = new Polygon(4);

  It will execute the constructor.

Comment: I'm confused, you said the method call to getSides is executed before the constructor

Comment: Yes, it is executed before the constructor. 

The constructor is the first method that is executed when creating objects.

Your problem is that you are assign a variable with the result of a method, and this method uses another instance variable.    So, the method is executed with the values that you declared and initialized(will use the default value if you did not defined)

Comment: But if the method is executed after constructor why isnt it executed using the new value of the instance variable instead of the default value?

Comment: Bro, I will edit my answear and put an example. Take a look

Answer (score 2):

in function `getSides()` you defined a new array of `sides`, which you didn't called the class instance variable which you defined as `int[] sides = this.getSides();`

```
int[] getSides() {
    sides = new int[this.num];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter length of side " + (i + 1));
        sides[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
    return sides;
}
```

complete code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polygon {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;

    Polygon(int n) {
        this.num = n;
    }

    int[] getSides() {
        this.sides = new int[this.num];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter length of side " + (i + 1));
            sides[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
        return sides;
    }

    int[] sides = this.getSides();
}
```

Runner Class:

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygon rectangle = new Polygon(4);
        int[] sides = rectangle.getSides();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rectangle.sides));
    }
}
```

For a Better Code you can write your `Polygon` class as below:

```
public class Polygon {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;
    int[] sides;

    Polygon(int n) {
        this.num = n;
        this.sides = new int[this.num];
    }

    int[] getSides() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter length of side " + (i + 1));
            sides[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sides));
        return sides;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not gonna work. Try to move System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rectangle.sides)); before getSides call, you will get empty array also.

Comment: I changed the code `int[] sides = new int[this.num];` to `sides = new int[this.num];` and it worked correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works for the given test case. but it won't initialize the sides field when the object is created.

Comment: im sorry, why did removing int[] from the beginning of the statement work?

Comment: @SatvikGupta because it make another new sides and didn't reference the current one.
for better understanding you could call `this.sides`

Comment: @SatvikGupta I added a better and cleaned code for your problem, which prevent from logical errors.

Comment: @SatvikGupta that is called shadowing. For more info, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-variable-shadowing-in-java  -- basically when there are two variables with the same name at different scopes, the  most immediate scope is used